# Intercept the Validation error from Flask restplus namespace class

Tags: flask, exception, flask-restful, flask-restplus

Currently the Namespace parser validates the request arguments and throws error like

```
{
    "errors": {
        "file": "Missing required parameter in an uploaded file"
    },
    "message": "Input payload validation failed"
}
```

From the flask-app i want to intercept or handle these exceptions and send a customised response for consistency like 
{
        "errors": {
            "file": "Missing required parameter in an uploaded file"
        },
        "message": "Input payload validation failed",
        "id" : "some customer id "
    }

Is it possible to handle this exception from app level instead of doing it for every api

Answer (score 3):

According to this issue https://github.com/noirbizarre/flask-restplus/issues/530 there is a workaround to have a personalized message.

That said, it is possible to implement this with the definition of the BadRequest error handler and modify the data attribute:

```
@api.errorhandler(BadRequest)
def bad_request(self):
    self.data.update({'id': 'some customer id'})

    return {}, 400
```

Though, there is no clean way to avoid the empty dictionary return, as it is discarded.